# List index out of range when using list[] instead of range() when iterating through the array

Tags: python, range

I was working on this question on Coding Bat, Warmup-2 > array_front9:

Given an array of ints, return True if one of the first 4 elements in the array is a 9. The array length may be less than 4.

Examples:

```
array_front9([1, 2, 9, 3, 4]) → True
array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 9]) → False
array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) → False
```

Here is my solution that works:

```
def array_front9(nums):
  if len(nums) >= 4: 
    for i in range(0,4):
      if nums[i] == 9:
        return True
    return False
  elif 0 <= 0 < 4:
    for i in range(len(nums)):
      if nums[i] == 9:
        return True
    return False
  else:
    if len(nums) == 0:
      return False
```

However, in line 3, if I try to iterate through the list by writing this instead:

`for i in num[0:4]:`

I would get an list index out of range error. Can someone please help me to understand why I cannot do it this way?

Thank you!

Comment: What is this - ```elif 0 <= 0 < 4:``` ? And also what should you return if len of array is less than 4 ?

Comment: Because if the list has less than 4 elements, you can't get a sublist of 4 elements from it, hence the error.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest going through the basics of python before doing coding problems. This function should be 1-2 lines.

Comment: ```for i in num[0:4]:``` is iterating over the elements of list. Ex, if length of a list is 9, and ```i=9```, you cannot fetch the index as it doesn't exists

Comment: Pay attention, you don't have num list in your code,  so you should use nums rather than num!!!

Comment: Thanks @HosseinVejdani! I actually wrote nums in the answer sheet but not here because I wasn't paying attention XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a 2 liner version:

```
def array_front9(nums):
   return 9 in nums[:4]
```

The problem with your code:

`for i in num[0:4]:` is iterating over the elements of list. Ex, if length of a list is 9, and `i=9`, you cannot fetch the index as it doesn't exists

Comment: Thank you so much Sujay. I got it now! Also, I am trying to learn Python by myself, so that's why I was trying to do what the instruction literally asked for - return True or False - and did not know that I could have Python return True or False, without even telling it to do so.

Comment: @alibaba456, Most welcome. Consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to over complicate things :

Just do this :

```
def array_front9(nums):
    return 9 in nums[:4]

print(array_front9([1, 2, 3, 9]),array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 9]),array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
# True False False
```

This will just check first 4 element of list provided and return True or False according!

And also if you use `lambda` one line :

```
array_front9=lambda nums: 9 in nums[:4]
print(array_front9([1, 2, 3, 9]),array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 9]),array_front9([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
# True False False
```

Comment: This can also be simplified to a one liner with `return 9 in nums[:4]`

Comment: @ApplePie edited and made one liner using lambda :)

Comment: Thanks Xitiz! Sorry, I have only started to learn Python by myself and trying to practice using Coding Bat so perhaps I haven't had the full knowledge to write shorter codes : D!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an `IndexError` is because you are using `for i in nums[0:4]` in line 3 but you are NOT changing `nums[i]` to just `i`.

So the values of `nums` will be used as indices. If length of `nums` is 4 one of the value is 7, you look for value at `nums[7]` which doesn't exist.

Below is the correct usage of what you wish to do. *Assuming your function returns `False` if array size is less than 4.*

```
a = [1,4,5,6,9]
b = [9,7,5,6]
c = [1]
def array_front9(nums):
  if len(nums) >= 4: 
    for i in nums[0:4]:
      if i == 9:
        return True
  return False

print(array_front9(a))
print(array_front9(b))
print(array_front9(c))
```

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ram for the very clear demonstration by making it similar to my codes, it really helped me to visualize better!